# Why do both my GGA+U and HSE06 calculations suggest that my material is a semiconductor, when I know it should be a conductor?

Tags: electronic-transport

I am considering a material that exhibits metallic properties from the four probe measurements between 50-400K. Its electrical conductivity is about 15-20 S/cm and kept almost unchanged with temperatures. However, I estimated the density of states using the GGA+U for transition metal and compared it with the HSE06 method. Both show that the material has a large band gap, suggesting a semiconductor instead. I wonder which factors would cause this?

Comment: Is your material doped? Also, take into account that the calculations are done for 0K, so, maybe that temperatures can be enough to change the conductive behavior of your material.

Comment: No, it is not doped, but due to vacancies, transition metal ions have two different oxidation states. It is hard to estimate DOS at different temperatures.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer to this question yet? I made it more specific in my last comment, but I'd be curious to see if you have any updates from the last 5 months!

Comment: Isn’t it a polaron localization/delocalization problem? If it is a material with significant band gap when there are no vacancies present, your model is just calculating that with localized states.

Comment: @Greg, yes, I also think the reason is that GGA+U or HSE06 methods overestimate the localized states, so it results in weird data. GGA+U or HSE06 methods should not be applied in these cases.

Comment: @BinhThien It is not a GGA+U / HSE06 error, but a DFT error in general. Also, your model may not capture well the symmetry or other aspects of the problem, as the simulation of vacancies, doping, etc is not a trivial task.

Comment: vacancies mean doping, though this doping is caused by native point defect, i.e., here vacancies.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the DOS plots. What happens if you just use a GGA (without a Hubbard U)? How did you determine which value to use for your Hubbard U?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone would like to answer or if OP addresses suggestions/questions from the comments.